# Ruby upgrade (from 1.8.7) on Rails 3.0.20 application causing time zone weirdness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-2.1, ruby-enterprise-edition

I'm upgrading an big, old, clunky Rails application's Ruby (mostly so I don't have to re-install REE on my reformatted laptop) and I'm getting bitten pretty badly by timezone issues.  Basically, pulling datetimes out of the database is not converting them to local time correctly:

**New System - Ruby 2.1.2, Ubuntu 14.04**

```
>> Time.zone.name
=> "Central Time (US & Canada)"
>> ActiveRecord::Base.time_zone_aware_attributes
=> true
>> ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone
=> :utc
>> Transaction.last.created_at
=> 2014-07-15 02:09:02 UTC
>> Transaction.last.created_at_before_type_cast
=> 2014-07-15 02:09:02 UTC
>> Transaction.last.created_at.localtime
=> 2014-07-14 21:09:02 -0500
>> exit
$ date
Mon Jul 14 22:27:50 CDT 2014
```

**Old System - REE, Ubuntu 12.04**

```
>> Transaction.last.created_at
=> Mon, 14 Jul 2014 22:03:11 CDT -05:00
>> Transaction.last.created_at_before_type_cast
=> Tue Jul 15 03:03:11 UTC 2014
>> Transaction.last.created_at.localtime
=> Mon Jul 14 22:03:11 -0500 2014
```

As you can see, I've ensured that `time_zone_aware_attributes` is set, the zone is set (I set it in the environment.rb), and ActiveRecord *is* storing the times in UTC (as expected).  I'm so stumped on this.  Anyone have any ideas?

**Update**

```
  before :all do
    @current_tz = Time.zone
    Time.zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
  end

  after :all do
    Time.zone = @current_tz
  end

  it 'should report time as Pacific time' do
    shift = FactoryGirl.create(:shift)
    new_obj = Transaction.create(shift: shift, time: DateTime.new(2013, 3, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0), amount: 0)
    new_obj.reload
    I18n.localize(new_obj.time, format: :timeonly).should_not == '12:00 am' #We created it with a UTC date, but it should get I18n'd to Pacific time
  end

#en.yml
  time:
    formats:
      timeonly: "%l:%M %p"
```

The above test is *also* failing.  The I18n stuff seems totally broken.

**Update 2**

I seem to have isolated the problem to 1.9.3 -> 2.1.  Using 1.9.3 is fine, I suppose, and I guess I'll just run that on the new server until I upgrade Rails.  Sad.  I'd still love to hear any suggestions about fixes.

Comment: I ran your code on ruby 2.1 with rails 4.0 and the output of the i18n stuff was 5:00. Perhaps an incompatibility between rails 3.0.x and ruby 2.1? The earliest version of rails that was fully compatible with ruby 2.0 was something like 3.2.16, so I wouldn't be massively surprised if there were some things that were broken in when you combine rails 3.0 with ruby 2.1

Comment: Correct.  There are a couple of patches (one having to do with AR associations being broken) that I had to use to try to get them to be compatible, but this one was quite surprising.  Upgrading the project from 3.0 to 3.2 (or 4) is not really something I have time for now...  So I abandoned that goal of getting it running on Ruby 2.  =)  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the I18n helpers to format/offset your time output - and force timezone (if needed)

```
puts I18n.localize(Transaction.last.created_at, format: :long)
```

Or

```
Time.use_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)") do
  puts I18n.localize(Transaction.last.created_at, format: :long)
end
```

I recommend you set your default `Time.zone` to UTC as well and update it for each user explicitly as needed - here is a blog post that might be helpful: http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: Thank you, that is probably good long-term, but definitely unexpected on a Ruby upgrade...  This site is for a local market, so all users/operation is in one single time zone, but I am familiar with all of the set-timezone-per-user practices.

Comment: And also, rebuilding ALL the views for this application to use localized times like that is not really tractable.